# reading Binary files

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to read this binary file and print the numbers on the screen but it is printing weird characters.  I generated this binary file from MATLAB.  How can I display the data properly?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

ifstream::pos_type size;
char * memblock;

int main ()
{
   ifstream file ("seg.bin", ios::in|ios::binary|ios::ate);

   if (file.is_open())
   {
        size = (int)file.tellg();
        memblock = new char [size];
        file.seekg (0, ios::beg);
        file.read (memblock, size);
        file.close();

        cout << "the complete file content is in memory";

        for (int i=0;i<size;i++)
        {
            cout<<memblock[i]<<endl;
        }
    }
    else cout << "Unable to open file";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do this: `cout<<(int)memblock[i]<<endl;`

Comment: @sgar91 You would only do that if the raw data is of type `char`.  The OP hasn't told us what the datatype is.

Comment: remember to delete[] memblock afterward, to prevent memory leakage

Comment: You could use a std::vector<char> as data type for memblock to avoid any memory leak. You can use &memblock[0] to get a pointer to the raw memory where the data is stored. If you do this, you could read the file via std::vector<char> memblock(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(file), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());

Answer (score 1):

You're printing `char`s to the output, the representation of the `char` in the output is a character, and if the character you're sending to `std::cout` isn't printable you'll see nothing or in some cases you'll see *weird characters* (or in some cases a beep sound!).

Try to cast the `char` value to `int`:

```
std::cout << static_cast<int>(memblock[i]) << std::endl;
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The way you're iterating-printing the data you'll only get data of 8bits size (or the size you `char` is), let's supose you have the following data on your file:

```
00000FFF
```

Your output will be:

> 0
>
> 0
>
> 15
>
> 255

But if you're working with data of other sizes (`int` for example) you will expect an output of `4095` (or `0` and `4095` if your data is 16bits wide).

If is your case, try to read the data into an array of the data you're expecting:

```
const ifstream::pos_type size = file.tellg(); // do not cast the size!
const size_t elements = size / sizeof(int);   // <--- beware of the sizes!
memblock = new int [elements];                // Elements, not size

for (int i = 0; i < elements; ++i) // Elements! not size
{
    std::cout << memblock[i] << std::endl;
}
```

Another tips:

- Declare `size` and `elements` as const (you're not going to change them after reading): This shows to you and your workmates your intention to treat this variables as read-only.
- Do not cast `size` to `int`, use the type of return of `tellg()` or use `auto`: `const auto size = file.tellg();`: Why cast to another type? Use the same of the function you're calling! Casts may lead to overhead.
- Try to declare your variables in the tiniest scope and near the place you're going to use them: This will make your code more readable and maintainable.

Answer (score 0):

You need to know what the datatype stored in the file is.  Let's say it's `double`.  In that case, you can do this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i += sizeof(double))
{
    cout << *(double*)&memblock[i] << endl;
}
```

The other way to go about it is to read directly into an array of `double` to begin with.  Will leave that as an exercise.

Answer (score 0):

memblock is of type char that is why cout will make char print(ascii characters). 
What you want to in this case is to reinterpret_cast the memblock pointer to the pointer of the type that you need. 
Say you need double:

```
size = (int)file.tellg();
memblock = new char [size];
file.seekg (0, ios::beg);
file.read (memblock, size);
file.close();
double * fileContent = reinterpret_cast<double *>(memblock);
cout << "the complete file content is in memory";

int sizeOfFileContent = sizeof(memblock)/sizeof(double);
for (int i=0; i<sizeOfFileContent; i++)
{
   cout<<fileContent[i]<<endl;
}
```

Use only one pointer to reclaim memory, not to try to delete it multiple times!